# Is Keycode for Delete and Dot same using JQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to catch keycode for Dot and Delete but on different events.

```
function validateSomething(eve) {
var charCode = (eve.which) ? eve.which : eve.keyCode
if (charCode == 46)
  console.log("Killer Brand")
}
```

When i press DOT or Delete in textbox; on keypress call above function; the if statement executes on both. Why? How to resolve then?

Answer (score 0):

Use keydown event instead. As W3schools says:

> The onkeypress event is not fired for all keys (e.g. ALT, CTRL, SHIFT,
>   ESC) in all browsers. To detect only whether the user has pressed a
>   key, use the onkeydown event instead, because it works for all keys

So it can be detected with same codes on keypress. Read more here:

So, here is a working example: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="validateSomething(event)" />

function validateSomething(eve) {
var charCode = (eve.which) ? eve.which : eve.keyCode
if (charCode == 46) {
  console.log("Killer Brand")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fruitful suggestion. Will test :)